# Why isn't prism highlighting python?

Tags: python, html

Im attempting to highlight python code on a web page.

My code works when I use `language-css`, but when I attempt to use `language-python`, the syntax doesn't get highlighted

```
<head>
<link
rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.5.0/themes/prism.min.css"
/>
</head>


<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.5.0/prism.min.js"></script>

<pre><code class="language-python">
def function():
   return(3)
</code></pre>
</body>
```

my function is not highlighted, but if I change `language-python` to `language-css`, syntax highlights as expected.

Comment: checkout my answer if u satisfy then voteup so other developer can search easily

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For That U need to **`prism-python.min.js`** Download or used **CDN** i.e **Content delivery network**

You have 2 option Either use

1. `class="language-py"`
2. `class="language-python"`

It's depend upon your choice

Here is the Example

```html
<head>
<link
rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.5.0/themes/prism.min.css"
/>
</head>


<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.17.1/prism.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.17.1/components/prism-python.min.js"></script>

<pre><code class="language-python">
def median(pool):
    '''Statistical median to demonstrate doctest.
    >>> median([2, 9, 9, 7, 9, 2, 4, 5, 8])
    7
    '''
    copy = sorted(pool)
    size = len(copy)
    if size % 2 == 1:
        return copy[(size - 1) / 2]
    else:
        return (copy[size/2 - 1] + copy[size/2]) / 2
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
</code></pre>
</body>
```

Here Is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbhp4gwn/) u can edit or preview code

Checkout Link about **Prism** link [Here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/prism)